# How to convert pdf to xml /json using python code

Tags: python, pdf

Can any one help me on how to convert pdf file to xml file using python code? My pdf contains:

1. Unstructured data
2. It has images
3. Mathematical equations
4. Chemical Equations
5. Table Data
6. Logo's tag's etc.

I tried using `PDFMiner`, but my pdf data was not converted into `.xml/json` file format. Are there any libraries other than `PDFMiner`? `PyPDF2`, `Tabula-py`, `PDFQuery`, `comelot`, `PyMuPDF`, `pdf to dox`, `pandas`- these other libraries/utilities all not suitable for my requirement.
Please advise me on any other options. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would recommend you trying is GROBID (see [here](https://grobid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the full documentation). You can play with an online demo [here](https://cloud.science-miner.com/grobid/) to see if fits your needs (select TEI -> Process Fulltext Document, and upload a PDF). You can also check out [this](https://github.com/allenai/s2orc-doc2json) from the Allen Institute (it is based on GROBID and has a handy function for converting TEI.XML to JSON).

The other package which--obviously--does a good job is the Adobe PDF Extract API (see [here](https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/apis/pdf-extract)). It's of course a paid service but when you register for an account you get 1.000 document transactions for free. It's easy to implement in Python, [well documented](https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/docs/overview/pdf-extract-api/), and a good way for experimenting and getting a feel for the difficulties of reliable data extraction from PDF.

I worked with both options to extract text, figures, tables etc. from scientific papers. Both yielded good results. The main problem with out-of-the-box solutions is that, when you work with complex formats (or badly formatted docs), erroneously identified document elements are quite common (for example a footnote or a header gets merged with the main text). Both options are based on machine learning models and, at least for GROBID, it is possible to [retrain these models](https://grobid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Training-the-models-of-Grobid/) for your specific task (I haven't tried this so far, so I don't know how worthwhile it is).

However, if your target PDFs are all of the same (simple) format (or if you can control their format) you should be fine with either option.

Comment: thank you for quick response. But I need python libraries only. is there any suitable libraries for my requirement?

Comment: Beyond the ones you already listed, I don't know of any. Could you be a bit more specific about your requirements? Why, for example, doesn't pdfminer work for you?

Comment: @ ai4ki- Actually  I want to convert pdf file ( it contains math equations, chemical formulas, graphs ,images, text ,logs ,table data ,OCR data, scanned data , what not each and everything like engineering /medical book. So I want extract each and everything and converted into .xml format. I used  some modules like : pdfminer,math,itertools,html,binascii,re,itertools,matplotlib,networkx,numpy,pdfparser,HTMLParser,ConvexHull,Delaunay,BeautifulSoup,Counter,chain.But I am  not getting accurate output/result.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no python-only package, which offers what you need (if I'm not mistaken, it's basically impossible). Data extraction from PDFs is tricky and even advanced tools like GROBID or Adobe's PDF EXtract API can't deliver 100% accuracy, You might want to check out [this tool](https://papertohtml.org) with one of your docs to see how good it can get.